# Collect multiple values in different lists of a tuple by fold erlang

Tags: erlang, fold

I have to iterate a sequence having elements in a list like `Sequence = ["1","2","4","5"]`. Need to prepare 9 lists which can only be calculated from the `Sequence`. I have following foldl.

```
Accumulators = {[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []},
ReturnedTup = lists:foldl(fun(Seq, Acc) ->
       {AccF1,AccF2,AccF3, AccF4,AccF5,AccF6, AccF7,AccF8,AccF9} = Acc,
       F1 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F1"),
       F2 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F2"),
       F3 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F3"),
       ...
       F9 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F9"),
       [F1|AccF1], [F2|AccF2], [F3|AccF3], ...,[F9|AccF9],
       Acc      
     end, Accumulators, Sequence),
io:format("~p ReturnedTup", [ReturnedTup]).
```

But here I'm getting `ReturnedTup` empty as `{[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []}`. I'm not sure whats wrong in it. I'm getting proper values in `F1, F2, F3... F9`.

I'm newbie to erlang. There could be efficient way to do this. If so, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function in foldl always returns initial accumulator:

```
Acc
```

You need to return new acc which must be a tuple that contains updated lists.:

```
Accumulators = {[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []},
ReturnedTup = lists:foldl(fun(Seq, Acc) ->
       {AccF1,AccF2,AccF3, AccF4,AccF5,AccF6, AccF7,AccF8,AccF9} = Acc,
       F1 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F1"),
       F2 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F2"),
       F3 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F3"),
       ...
       F9 = get_seq_indexlist(Seq, "F9"),
       {[F1|AccF1], [F2|AccF2], [F3|AccF3], ...,[F9|AccF9]}
     end, Accumulators, Sequence),
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Rubber Cthulu is only beginning :)

It would be good to remove the code duplication. If you are copy pasting something nine times - it is hard to maintain.

```
Sequence = ["1","2","4","5"],
Accumulators = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
CounterToString = fun(Integer) -> "F"++integer_to_list(Integer) end,
FoldlFun = fun(SequenceElement, Acc) ->
                   PrependSeqIndexList = fun(Counter, InnerAcc) ->
                                                [get_seq_indexlist(SequenceElement, CounterToString(Counter)) | InnerAcc] end,
                   {NewAccs, _LastCounter} = lists:mapfoldl(fun(InnerAcc, Counter) ->
                                                                    {PrependSeqIndexList(Counter, InnerAcc),
                                                                     Counter+1} end, 1, Acc),
                   NewAccs
           end,
ReturnedList = lists:foldl(FoldlFun, Accumulators, Sequence),
ReturnedTup = list_to_tuple(ReturnedList),
io:format("~p ReturnedTup", [ReturnedTup]).
```

- I would change `Seq` to `SequenceElement`, because function, that is argument of `foldl/3` takes sequence element and not entire sequence. Or you can name it `InnerSequence` - doesn't matter.
- You want to iterate over inner accumulators, so make them a list
- Use mapfoldl to iterate over inner accumulators - it works like map, but it also has accumulator, that we will use for counter.
- If your really need return value in tuple, use `list_to_tuple/1` at the end
- Name your helpers, this makes it easier to read the code.
- If you create fun inside another fun, you can use outer fun arguments. `PrependSeqIndexList` uses `SequenceElement` even though it is in outer scope. It is called closure.
- There are other ways to improve this code - for example, it is still deeply nested, but I leave that as an exercise for you :)